# Django + dropzone.js: form validation fails for multiple files

Tags: django, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload multiple files in one request using dropzone.js.  When I set the `uploadMultiple` option to true in dropzone, one request containing both files is sent to my view, but form validation fails.

Here is my Django form:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
  data = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
  file = forms.FileField()
```

My view:

```
def upload(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    print request.FILES

    if form.is_valid():
      for file in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
        print str(file)

    else:
      print form.errors

  else:
    form = UploadForm(initial={'data': 5})

  return render(request, 'upload.html', {
    'form': form
    })
```

and my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  autoProcessQueue : false,
  uploadMultiple: true,

  init : function() {
    myDropzone = this;

    this.element.querySelector("input[type='submit']").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
  }
}
</script>

<form id='my-awesome-dropzone' class="dropzone"
    action="{% url 'upload.views.upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.data }}

<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I see that `request.FILES` has two files:

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'file[]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Forest Flowers.jpg (image/jpeg)>,
    <InMemoryUploadedFile: Forest.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

I guess the issue is Django doesn't recognize `file[]`.  It expects `file` instead.  How can I get Django to recognize the two uploads?

Comment: You definitely can do multifile upload. I did that with dropzone and django  in the past however I'm not at office now so I cannot copy the important aspects of my code to give you hints. I remember I started developing from this article: http://mechanicalgirl.com/post/batch-image-upload-drag-and-drop-django-admin/ - it should answer your last question

Comment: you can use this `for file in request.FILES.getlist('file[]'):
        print str(file)`

Comment: @furins , I have implemented the dropzone with django template,  but the images are not getting upload at server side. can you suggest me what is going wrong. I also gone through the link you mentioned link also

Comment: @MegaBytes: do you get a specific error? Do you have some code I can look at in order to reproduce it? Eventually, please consider to open a new question if it is different from user2233706 one or mechanicalgirl's one.

Comment: @furins, `MultiValueDictKeyError at /saveimages/` and says No Files DATA in request, yes sure I am raising a new question with code snippet.

Comment: @furins, please join this discuss group. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71272/python-django-dropzone

Comment: @furins, please can you look my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623094/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-django-using-dropzone-for-multiple-image-fields

Answer (score 1):

You are right assuming that the validation error is originated because of the input name dropzone.js sends to the server. The "file[n]" pattern when your Django form is expecting a field named "file" throws a validation error (required field).

In Dropzone.js you can specify the parameter "paramName" and this object property also accepts a function instead of a simple string, so if you set your paramName to something like:

```
...
paramName: function(){
    return "file";
}
...
```

the name of the field sent to server doesn't change and you get a "file" field in request.FILES that is a dict with one element (file) that is an array of files as it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
file1 = request.FILES.get(file[][0], None)  # For the first file
file2 = request.FILES.get(file[][1], None)  # For the second file
```

... and so on...

Hope that helps.