# Trying to use django and dropzone/

Tags: django, django-views, dropzone.js, django-file-upload

I'm trying to use dropzone.js with django.

I'm following the somewhat dated guide here (https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/dropzonejs-django-how-to-build-a-file-upload-form/)

I strongly suspect My view is at issue.

```
def test(request):
    print "test view has been called"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "test request method is POST"
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print request
        print request.FILES
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = AttachedFiles(attachedfile=request.FILES['file'])
            new_file.save()
            id = new_file.pk
            print id
            print "test form valid"
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'id': id}), content_type="application/json")
       print "test form not valid"
   else:
       form = UploadFileForm()
   data = {'form': form}
   return render_to_response('mediamanager/test.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've tested submitting to it with the dropzone code

```
        <!-- IMPORTANT enctype attribute! -->
    <form id="my_dropzone" class="dropzone" action="/mediamanager/test/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
     <button id="submit-all">
        Submit all files
    </button>
    </form>
    <script src="{% static 'dropzone/js/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

            // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue : true,

            init : function() {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                myDropzone = this;

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                });

                // You might want to show the submit button only when
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("addedfile", function() {
                    // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                    console.log("blah")
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
```

and a basic form

```
<form action="{% url "test" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the form is never valid.
I'm using a modelform as suggested

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AttachedFiles
```

Comment: What you want to do, are you uploading images or which type of files.?

Comment: I'd like to be able to upload any type of file at this stage. In the end I want them attached to another model.

Comment: In the end I want a multiple file uploader to attach multiple files to a model..... I've been struggling with this for weeks.

Comment: I had also struggled with this problem where I have to upload multiple images. I solve this using my way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623094/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-django-using-dropzone-for-multiple-image-fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle Dropzone posts like any other multipart form post.

Here's how I proceed:

```py
@login_required
@usertype_required
def upload_picture(request, uid=None):
    """
    Photo upload / dropzone handler
    :param request:
    :param uid: Optional picture UID when re-uploading a file.
    :return:
    """
    form = PhotoUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        pic = request.FILES['file']
        # [...] Process whatever you do with that file there. I resize it, create thumbnails, etc.
        # Get an instance of picture model (defined below) 
        picture = ...         
        picture.file = pic
        picture.save()
        return HttpResponse('Image upload succeeded.')
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Image upload form not valid.")
```

The form is dead simple

```py
class PhotoUploadForm(forms.Form):
    # Keep name to 'file' because that's what Dropzone is using
    file = forms.ImageField(required=True)
```

In your model you need the upload_to set:

```py
class Picture(models.Model):
    [...]
    # Original
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

And here's my upload path builder, but you can put anything

```py
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ creates unique-Path & filename for upload """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.p_uid, ext)
    d = datetime.date.today()
    username = instance.author.username

    #Create the directory structure
    return os.path.join(
        'userpics', username, d.strftime('%Y'), d.strftime('%m'), filename
    )
```

Don't forget the csrf_token in the html form itself (I'm using an angularJS directive on top of it so will be different for you)

```html
<form action="{% url 'upload_picture' %}" class="dropzone" drop-zone>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="fallback">
        <h3>Your browser is not supported.</h3>
        <strong>
            <a href="https://browser-update.org/update.html" target="_blank">Click here for instructions on how to update it.</a>
        </strong>
        <p>You can still try to upload your pictures through this form: </p>
        <p>
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got dropzone js working by modifying the bootstrap example (I am using bootstrap) here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html

I do not use any forms. I got a view handling the in coming ajax posts from dropzone. Here is the gist of my view code:

```
class AjaxUploadView(View):
    """
        View for uploading via AJAX.
    """
    def post_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        # Do stuff with file
        # Return appropriate response
```

Hope it helps.